# UITouch events calls / works only once. not works second time,

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitouch, gmsmapview

In my application **i have added a google maps on my view.**

**`I want to know the touch point on the mapView / myView,`** where did i taped

So that i implemented logic as follows.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint  = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:mapView_];
     CGPoint touchPoint2  = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];



    NSLog(@"========== %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
    NSLog(@"========== %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint2));

   //UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     //CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

}
```

But **it works only for the first touch**, from the next touch event this method doesn't calls.

I didn't get what was the problem is

Comment: i've tried this code only and surprisingly it calls each and every time i touch inside view at any point and logs the value perfectly

Comment: yes it works for all other views very well.. but, not in my current view which is having google map view

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the touch loctaion on a map,when we touch it ,it becomes zoom,the touch events is on the UIView

Comment: who told you that we can not have touch event on map? and map zooms only if we touble tap on it.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of this i get a log at everytime i touch on mapview with exact touch points

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint  = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.viewMap];
    NSLog(@"==========1 %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
}
```